# how to post array of unknown depth/length to c#/mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, formcollection

My background is primarily PHP, so i'm used to being able to use deep arrays in forms very easily.  What I need is the c#/MVC equivelant of the following:

```
<input type="text" name="data[0][index_name][0]">
<input type="text" name="data[0][index_name][1]">
<input type="text" name="data[1][index_name][0]">
<input type="text" name="data[1][index_name][1]">
<input type="text" name="data[2][index_name][0][something_else]">
<input type="text" name="data[2][index_name][0]">
<input type="text" name="data[2][index_name][1]">
```

These could then be accessed in this way in php...

```
$_POST['data'][0]['index_name'][0];
$_POST['data'][0]['index_name'][1];
$_POST['data'][1]['index_name'][0];
$_POST['data'][1]['index_name'][1];
$_POST['data'][2]['index_name'][0]['something_else'];
$_POST['data'][2]['index_name'][0];
$_POST['data'][2]['index_name'][1];
```

I've tried looking at/looping over the formColletion object i receive, but the keys are simply the name attribute string, such as "data[2][index_name][0][something_else]," and there is no depth to the data.

How do I parse this data and put in some usable data type?  I do not know how deep the array will be as the form changes dynamically on the front end.

So you have some context, this will is being used to build a "table" of data that has a flexible number of rows and columns and each row can be treated as a standard row or grouping row (meaning it contains other rows), so the data can, in theory, get very deep.

On a side note, i've also thought about cleaning up the data on the client side, but it appears there's nothing standard out there that supports this.  Jquery.serialize and JQuery.serializeArray() do the same thing as C#/MVC and simply index everything with the full name attribute without taking into account the array indexes.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You will probably get more response if you do not assume that those of us who know c# well enough to answer, also under stand your PHP code and references (like "depth").

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to clarify.  The way you access different levels of an array is fairly common to most programming languages.  I believe you could consider a PHP array similar to a Dictionary in C#.  When i refer to depth, I'm simply referring to the different levels of, say, a Dictionary (e.g. - var["level1"]["level2"]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model Binding turned out to be the correct solution.  It support recursion out of the box.  Here is a nice write-up:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

Comment: I know this is very old question but I think Scott has explained [link]http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx in much easy to understand way

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the deep aspect but if you post items with the same name then MVC reconstructs this as an array.

```
<input type="hidden" name="MyArray" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="MyArray" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="MyArray" value="3"/>
<input type="hidden" name="MyArray" value="4"/>
```

And on your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyActionMethod(string[] MyArray)
{
  // Do stuff with MyArray
}
```

You can also access the `Request.Form` collection in the controller. The key is from the name part of the input on the HTML form.

You can access it like this:

```
Request.Form["data[2][index_name][0][something_else]"]
```

Or iterate over it like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyActionMethod()
{
  foreach(var key in Request.Form.Keys)
  {
    var item = Request.Form[key];
    // Do stuff with each item
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm able to access teh data this way, but having to use Request.Form["data[2][index_name][0][something_else]"] does not help me put the data in a usable format.  I could parse the key string and rebuild the data, but it seems there has to be a better/cleaner solution